# Vendoring python packages for a published package

Tags: python, python-packaging

I currently have a package that I would like to publish to pypi, which requires another package (https://github.com/CrisisTextLine/scrubadub) that is a fork of the original scrubadub package. I am trying to vendor the scrubadub fork, but I haven't found any resource on how to vendor packages in python.

I'd like to support python2 and python3 for the package I distribute. My concerns include:

- where to place the vendorized packages
- how to get the packages themselves - should I simply place the source into this vendor folder
- how to manage dependencies of the vendored packages - should I add their dependencies in my dependency list in setup.py?

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are redistributing

- check if the license is compatible
- Copy the code into your modules folder
- Update all the import statements until all the imports resolve again
- Include licenses for vendorized
- Yes, you'll need to either vendorize dependencies, or at least add them to your own dependency list in setup.py.

Consider using something like [python-vendorize](https://pypi.org/project/vendorize/) to automate and make the workflow less ad hoc.

If you are not redistributing, then the vendor folder acts sort of like a manual virtual environment folder or extra site-packages folder.

- add a folder, e.g. `/vendor/`
- copy all vendorized modules there.
- You don't have to update namespaces
- You could `pip install . -e` them, or add their dependencies to your dependency files (requirements.txt, Pipfile, etc)
- Update PYTHONPATH to include the `/vendor/` folder.

Consider using something like [Vendy](https://pypi.org/project/vendy/) to automate this and make the workflow less ad hoc.

Comment: Sadly none of the two mentioned utilities seems to be actively maintained, I guess we are better off DIY.

Comment: Or you could vendorize them, eh?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, if you are about to use a tool to ease the vendoring process instead of DIY (manually), I would recommend https://pypi.org/project/vendoring/ because that is used actively by pip itself.

There were other projects but I checked them and they do not seem to be actively maintained.

Comment: It would be nice if the repo, didn't have a big warning label  on the box. Also, the method of patching the imports, and also throwing warning when including `*.so` files, is a bit of a higher bar.