# How to distribute a package with self-contained local dependencies?

Tags: python, pip

I have some local packages hosted on my own machine, I would like to include a copy of them in distribution of other packages that depends on them. When installing a local package, `pip freeze` shows something like

```
public-package==3.0.1
local-package @ file:///home/user/local-package/dist/local-package-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

but if one try to install that package on other computer will get error from pip because `local-package` path does not exist. Can I extend `setup.py` commands to process that `requirements.txt` file, extract local packages path, copy local packages into `deps` folder of dist archive and rewrite `requirements.txt` like

```
public-package==3.0.1
local-package @ deps/local-package-1.0.0.tar.gz
```

and make pip treat `deps/` as a relative path to the package archive itself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62070316/4478375 but there is not approved answer

Comment: You can not rely on custom code in `setup.py`, this will not actually work, because most of the time that file is not executed at installation-time. -- I do not know your specific use case, but you probably should consider publishing this `local-package`, it would make things much simpler.

Comment: Well I can't publish it that's why I am trying to bundle them together.

Comment: Is `public-package` a library or an application? Have you considered _vendoring_?

Comment: I was thinking in using pip's `extra-index-urls` but I found `pip install` command can't be extended, it does not runs `setup.py` install commands even for source distributions. That vendoring works without chaging any import? I need to handle their dependencies too.

Comment: `public-package` was just an example of a package published in pypi, `local-package` is a private package, thus can't be published.

Comment: I found `setup.py install` is ran for source distributions but only after all dependencies are installed but actually I need to override dependencies resolving logic, so it's needed to change pip itself.

Comment: I think that in your case you could vendor while keeping the same top-level packages and/or modules, so that there would be no need to change the imports. -- The trick with custom `setup.py` would only work in specific cases (unless, maybe, you do weird things like preventing wheels from being built). -- Your package is not really private since you want it to be installed anyway, so where do you draw the line here? Why not distribute wheels of this private package? What's the difference? (Genuinely asking)

Comment: Well maybe wrong words, I want to distribute but only for authorized people but I don't want to host a pypi server. The best way for that is just bundle private dependencies along with package itself. I wonder why this is not suṕported since pip allows one to install packages from local files.

Comment: But how do you distribute the public part? If you bundle the private dependency inside the distributions of the public one, then everything is public, isn't it? I guess I do not understand what you are trying to achieve here...

Comment: `local-package` is private because for someone to use they must be authorized... i.e. they can have access to the package and its bundled private dependencies.

Comment: I found with source distributions it seems to be possible to monkeypatch pip and make it search dependencies inside distribution archive, it's possible because pip loads setup.py module before starting installation. I will try to develop a package for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with source distributions and overriding `sdist` and `egg_info` commands to make setuptools bundle local dependencies together with package and to make pip search dependencies in that bundle when installing the built package later. But later I figured out it makes system vulnerable to [dependency confusion](https://medium.com/@alex.birsan/dependency-confusion-4a5d60fec610) attacks because local packages installed from that bundle are visible with `pip freeze`, if for some reason the dependency location, like `local-package @ file:///home/user/packages/local-package.tar.gz` is stripped to just `local-package` pip will search it on pypi, which allows dependency confusion to happen.

The best solution for this problem is to vendor all local dependencies where their source code is copied to the package, pip itself vendors its dependencies using [vendoring](https://pypi.org/project/vendoring/).